# How to translate a Select with uuid to plpgsql in java

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, uuid

I have the following simple select:

```
SELECT * FROM db.table WHERE uuid::varchar LIKE ('389519a6-ba79-4a4d-a696-c818808d3b26');
```

which works just fine in pgadmin v4.

Now I try to do the same with a plpgsql function:

```
 queries[0] = "DROP FUNCTION createtemptable(text,text,text);"
            + "CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION createTempTable(name TEXT, id TEXT, units TEXT) "
            + "RETURNS void AS $$ "
            + "DECLARE "
            + "nameid TEXT; "
            + "BEGIN "
            + "nameid := name || id;"
            + "EXECUTE 'SET search_path = schema_name; "
            + "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ' || quote_ident(nameid) || ' "
            + "AS SELECT * FROM ' || quote_ident(name) || ' "
            + "WHERE uuid LIKE ' || uuid(units) ;"
            + "END; $$ "
            + "LANGUAGE plpgsql;";
```

resulting in:

```
DROP FUNCTION createtemptable(text,text,text);
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION createTempTable(name TEXT, id TEXT, units TEXT)
RETURNS void AS $$ 
DECLARE nameid TEXT; 
BEGIN 
    nameid := name || id;
    EXECUTE 
        'SET search_path = opsim; 
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ' || quote_ident(nameid) || ' AS 
            SELECT * FROM ' || quote_ident(name) || ' 
                WHERE uuid LIKE ' || uuid(units);
END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

In the end I want to hand over an array of unit uuids and have a temp_table created for them. In the last few hours I traced the error back to the select on top.

What's weird: it works just fine in pgadmin, but fails with:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Error: Syntaxerror at „a6“
```

It doesn't matter if I keep both as uuids, or compare them as strings, it always breaks at that point. And I can't find out why.

According to auntie google and everything I researched in the last 4 hours, it should work. Anyone an idea where I forgot to mask something or ... whatever?

EDIT: improved on suggestions from comments. I can't quote_ident units, as this would add unwanted quotes.

Comment: How it is related to `java`?

Comment: You're not properly quoting any of your inputs, which (aside from being a risky injection point) is resulting in a broken query. Check `quote_literal()` and `quote_ident()` for quoting your inputs before embedding them in that query string or use `format()` to quote and embed in one shot.

Comment: *nod* understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `format()` to safely format dynamic SQL statements:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION createTempTable(name TEXT, id TEXT, units TEXT) 
   RETURNS void 
AS 
$$ 
BEGIN 
  EXECUTE format(
    'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS db.%I AS 
     SELECT * 
     FROM db.%I
     WHERE uuid = %L', name||id, name, units);
END; 
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

It's unclear to me why you are using `where uuid IN (...)` if you are only passing a single value.

If you want to pass multiple values for the UUID, use an array rather then a comma separated string:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION createTempTable(name TEXT, id TEXT, units TEXT[]) 
   RETURNS void 
AS 
$$ 
BEGIN 
  EXECUTE format(
    'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %I AS 
     SELECT * 
     FROM %I
     WHERE uuid::varchar = any($1)', name||id, name) using units;
END; 
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

You use it like this:

```
select createtemptable(
        'anders', 
        'one', 
        array['389519a6-ba79-4a4d-a696-c818808d3b26','389519a6-ba77-4a4d-a696-c818808d3b26']
       );
```

Here is an example: http://rextester.com/SOAK47342

Comment: I'm using IN as I want to change this function later on to acceot an array. Or rather: I had it layed out that way, and downscaled to remove the error.
But the problem seems to be independent from any lack of formating or such. Even after reformating it seems as if the conversion stops whenever it encounters a sign instead of a number inside the uuid string.

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name can you please put your comment as an answer? it works perfectly, and I want to vote you up for it. :D I just don't understand why the last version I used didn't work as well.

Comment: As said ahwnn, NO clue, why format works, while my above version doesn't. It should be identical.

Comment: @AndersBernard: I added a version that supports multiple uuid values through an array